# Eclipse asking for proxy auth when i dont req an auth

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, automated-tests

I use a proxy to access internet in my VDI.
On launching eclipse im asked for a proxy auth.

There is no auth req for my proxy. i am able to browse without any auth.

Im installing eclipse for the first time and need to download some plug ins
i have tried changing my proxy to Manual/Native/Direct
I have aslo tried editing my ini file with

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
-Dhttp.proxyPort=xxxx
-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxxx
-Dhttp.proxyUser=aaaaa\xxasds
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=xxx
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|192.168.*|10.*
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Comment: Just a question: if -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true is set, and you already configuredthe system proxies in the operating system, then why you specify http.proxyUser and http.proxyHost? Using java.net.useSystemProxies is mutually exclusive with specifying explicite proxy informations.

Comment: I have tried having the -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true only in my ini file.. Still i do face the proxy auth issue

Comment: For which URL you are asked for proxy authentication (HTTP or HTTPS)? When exactly do you get which error message? Do you have a proxy and if so, with or without authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @howlger I am using a proxy.pac in my system proxy . In eclipse IDE when i have my settings to native i get error while accessing MPC :Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: HTTP Proxy Authentication Required

IN case i Choose Manual proxy in IDE giving the proxy IP in the host for Http/Https
i am able to open the MPC and on trying to install any plug in i get
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required:

I dont have any credentials for the proxy

Please advise.. I am not even able to get started with eclipse